# Repetitions on regexp_replace

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, getfeature, regular-expression

I'm using regexp_replace to replace expressions like 'Xm1 and Xm2'but also 'Xm11 and Xm2' or 'Xm22 and Xm11' with a text i have on a spreadsheet;

Basically i want to make a VLOOKUP on Qgis between the shapefile i want to edit and a table i made in excel where i will get the values from.

My spreadsheet: [XM] - 'Xm1' = [SOLO] - 'QGIS ROCKS' || [XM] - 'Xm2' = [SOLO] - 'EXCEL ROCKS', where [XM] and [SOLO] are the table headers. 'Xm1' and 'Xm2' are the keys to look up and the texts on [SOLO] field. I want to incorporate the exppression becoming like 'QGIS rocks and EXCEL ROCKS'

My expression looks like this:

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace( regexp_replace( 
regexp_replace(   "XM"  , 'Xm1', attribute( get_feature( 
'spreadsheet','XM','Xm1'),'SOLO')),'Xm2',attribute( get_feature( 
'spreadsheet','XM','Xm2'),'SOLO')),'Xm3',attribute( get_feature( 
'spreadsheet','XM','Xm3'),'SOLO')),'Xm4', attribute( get_feature( 
'spreadsheet','XM','Xm4'),'SOLO')),'Xm5',attribute( get_feature( 
'spreadsheet','XM','Xm5'),'SOLO')),'Xm6', attribute( get_feature( 
'spreadsheet','XM','Xm6'),'SOLO')),'Xm7', attribute( get_feature( 
'spreadsheet','XM','Xm7'),'SOLO')),'Xm8', attribute( get_feature( 
'spreadsheet','XM','Xm8'),'SOLO')),'Xm9', attribute( get_feature( 
'spreadsheet','XM','Xm9'),'SOLO'))
```

which works fine on these replacements until I add this replacement:

```
regexp_replace('Xm11', attribute( get_feature( 'spreadsheet','XM','Xm11'),'SOLO'))
```

Already tried to build a model and insert this last expression on another field calculator, but there might be a conflict between Xm1 and Xm11. Also tried do use special characters like \bXm1\b and \bXm11\b on both (value to replace and value to look up on spreadsheet). Till 9 replacements it works ok, but since i add 'Xm10', 'Xm11' etc... happens that it doesn't even fill the fields with the previous replacements.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To me, this sounds like an XY problem, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/930719 Can you explain a bitte more detailed what kind of data you have and what you want to achieve? Repeating the same `regex_replace()` function again and again does not seem to be a good solution to me.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with `[XM] - 'Xm1' = [SOLO] - 'QGIS ROCKS' || [XM] - 'Xm2' = [SOLO] - 'EXCEL ROCKS'`. Please add your project + data for testing. Othewise, I don't see how it should be possible to help

Comment: You are trying with `\b` but the answer provided to your previous question uses `\\b`, and it works. `regexp_replace('b10','1\\b','X')` -> `b10`, `regexp_replace('b10','10\\b','X')` -> `bX`

Comment: @Babel [XM] and [SOLO] are the headers of my spreadsheet. What i want is a VLOOKUP on QGIS, and that works fine with field calculator if i use just 9 values and 9 keys (Xm1; Xm2; Xm3, ... Xm9). The moment i add the replace for Xm11 it doesn't work.